How to query with LINQ a dictionary property in EF Core with Cosmos DB provider
I have a class Entity mapped with EF Core to a Cosmos DB container. The class has a property Labels of type Dictionary<string, string>. How can I find all instances of that class that have say Labels["thing"] == "one". The line: context.Entities.Where(e => e.Labels["thing"] == "one").ToList() throws an exception:

System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression DbSet<Entity>().Where(e => e.Labels.get_Item("thing") == "one") could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation...


Unfortunately, I have not been able to make EF work so far, so I resorted to using the Azure Cosmos DB SDK:
var dbName = context.Database.GetCosmosDatabaseId() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
var client = context.Database.GetCosmosClient() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
var database = client.GetDatabase(dbName) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();
var entitiesContainer = database.GetContainer("Entity") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

using var iterator = entitiesContainer
                        .GetItemLinqQueryable<Entity>()
                        .Where(
                            e =>
                                //e.Labels.ContainsKey("label1")
                                //&&
                                e.Labels["label1"] == "value1"
                            )
                        .ToFeedIterator()
                        ;

List<Entity> list = [];

while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    list.AddRange(await iterator.ReadNextAsync());

Note that ContainsKey still doesn't work - it throws a similar exception, but apparently, the CosmosDB SDK manages just fine without it.

To query your Entity class that has a Labels property of type Dictionary<string, string> in EF, you can't use the indexing syntax (like Labels["thing"]) directly. This leads to an error because that part of the LINQ expression can’t be translated into a format that Cosmos DB understands.
Instead, you can check if the dictionary contains the key using ContainsKey and then compare the value. Something like this:
var results = context.Entities
.Where(e => e.Labels.ContainsKey("thing") && e.Labels["thing"] == "one")
.ToList();

Or this other approach that I wouldn't recommend where the db don't handle the filtering
var results = context.Entities
.ToList()
.Where(e => e.Labels.ContainsKey("thing") && e.Labels["thing"] == "one")
.ToList();


All that you are saying is true for EF in general, but unfortunately, it is not helpful in this case. In the sample, I left the shortest possible version of the query, and yes, in my original code, I do have the ContainsKey check, which also throws a similar exception. The problem is with the EF provider - as stated in the title - the provider for Azure Cosmos DB. The documentation states that they support dictionaries of primitive types and strings but apparently only for store and retrieval, not for query.
